# stm32h7 rtc resets after power down (vbat is connected)

Tags: stm32, real-time-clock, stm32h743

I am using a stm32h753 and stm32cubemx, and trying to run the RTC module on VBAT. To do this I have connected a battery to the MCU. RTC is connected to LSE. Next, I set the RTC in my code and then I disconnect the MCU from power source, and then reconnect it again. Based on the documentation, this should automatically switch the RTC power source from VDD to VBAT.

I have commented the MX_RTC_Init() in the startup, so that RTC is not reset when the MCU restart.

Below are the code for system clock config, RTC Init, and the code to read the RTC registers after reset.

```
    void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Supply configuration update enable 
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ConfigSupply(PWR_LDO_SUPPLY);
  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  while(!__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_VOSRDY)) {}
  /** Configure LSE Drive Capability 
  */
  HAL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();
  __HAL_RCC_LSEDRIVE_CONFIG(RCC_LSEDRIVE_LOW);
  /** Macro to configure the PLL clock source 
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PLL_PLLSOURCE_CONFIG(RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE);
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSEState = RCC_LSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 84;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLRGE = RCC_PLL1VCIRANGE_3;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLVCOSEL = RCC_PLL1VCOWIDE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLFRACN = 0;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D3PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D1PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB3CLKDivider = RCC_APB3_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_APB1_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_APB2_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB4CLKDivider = RCC_APB4_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_RTC|RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART3
                              |RCC_PERIPHCLK_SPI1|RCC_PERIPHCLK_SDMMC
                              |RCC_PERIPHCLK_ADC;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL2.PLL2M = 1;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL2.PLL2N = 25;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL2.PLL2P = 4;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL2.PLL2Q = 2;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL2.PLL2R = 2;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL2.PLL2RGE = RCC_PLL2VCIRANGE_3;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL2.PLL2VCOSEL = RCC_PLL2VCOMEDIUM;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL2.PLL2FRACN = 0;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.SdmmcClockSelection = RCC_SDMMCCLKSOURCE_PLL;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.Spi123ClockSelection = RCC_SPI123CLKSOURCE_PLL;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.Usart234578ClockSelection = RCC_USART234578CLKSOURCE_D2PCLK1;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.AdcClockSelection = RCC_ADCCLKSOURCE_PLL2;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.RTCClockSelection = RCC_RTCCLKSOURCE_LSE;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

This is the RTC Init code

```
static void MX_RTC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 0 */

  RTC_TimeTypeDef sTime = {0};
  RTC_DateTypeDef sDate = {0};
  RTC_AlarmTypeDef sAlarm = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 1 */
  /** Initialize RTC Only 
  */
  hrtc.Instance = RTC;
  hrtc.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
  hrtc.Init.AsynchPrediv = 127;
  hrtc.Init.SynchPrediv = 255;
  hrtc.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutType = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutRemap = RTC_OUTPUT_REMAP_NONE;
  if (HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Check_RTC_BKUP */

  /* USER CODE END Check_RTC_BKUP */

  /** Initialize RTC and set the Time and Date 
  */
  sTime.Hours = 0x0;
  sTime.Minutes = 0x0;
  sTime.Seconds = 0x0;
  sTime.DayLightSaving = RTC_DAYLIGHTSAVING_NONE;
  sTime.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;
  if (HAL_RTC_SetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sDate.WeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
  sDate.Month = RTC_MONTH_JANUARY;
  sDate.Date = 0x1;
  sDate.Year = 0x0;
  if (HAL_RTC_SetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Enable the Alarm A 
  */
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.Hours = 0x0;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.Minutes = 0x20;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.Seconds = 0x0;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.SubSeconds = 0x0;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.DayLightSaving = RTC_DAYLIGHTSAVING_NONE;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;
  sAlarm.AlarmMask = RTC_ALARMMASK_DATEWEEKDAY|RTC_ALARMMASK_HOURS;
  sAlarm.AlarmSubSecondMask = RTC_ALARMSUBSECONDMASK_ALL;
  sAlarm.AlarmDateWeekDaySel = RTC_ALARMDATEWEEKDAYSEL_DATE;
  sAlarm.AlarmDateWeekDay = 0x1;
  sAlarm.Alarm = RTC_ALARM_A;
  if (HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&hrtc, &sAlarm, RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Enable the Alarm B 
  */
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.Minutes = 0x40;
  sAlarm.Alarm = RTC_ALARM_B;
  if (HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&hrtc, &sAlarm, RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 2 */

}
```

this is the code I use after startup to read the rtc register vallues:

```
HAL_RTC_GetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
HAL_RTC_GetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);

float subSecondsFloat = (  255 - sTime.SubSeconds );
subSecondsFloat = (subSecondsFloat /255);
subSecondsFloat = (subSecondsFloat * 1000);

year       = (uint32_t) (sDate.Year);
month      = (uint32_t) (sDate.Month);
day        = (uint32_t) (sDate.Date);

hours      = (uint32_t) (sTime.Hours);
minutes    = (uint32_t) (sTime.Minutes);
seconds    = (uint32_t) (sTime.Seconds);
subseconds = (uint32_t) (subSecondsFloat);

sprintf(usartSendBuffer,"\n%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu\n", year,month,day,hours, minutes,seconds,subseconds);

printf(usartSendBuffer);
```

When I disconnect the MCU from power source, and reconnect it to power source, the above code gives the following results (RTC register values) after a power reset:

159,10,9,32,51,51,4294967295

So the RTC is reset somewhere in the MCU reset. Considering that I have disabled the MX_RTC_Init(), I do not know where the RTC is reset.

sorry if the question is elementary, I am really new to this field.

I greatly appreciate any help, thank you.

Best regards,

Vouria

Comment: load an example form STM and see what steps you need. Your procedure is too simple

Comment: I checked and could not find any example. Usually this procedure is very simple, and no codes included. Switing from VDD power to VBat is done automatically within MCU. It is enough only when the battery is connected to Vbat pin. Thanks

Comment: I checked again, there are no examples for Vbat RTC

Comment: i see at least 3 projects for RTC. BTW there is nothig like Vbat RTC. RTC is only one.

Comment: you are right that there is no vbat rtc, by Vbat RTC I mean running the RTC on Battery when main power is not present. I just looked among the examples, they are related to RTC, but not to running RTC on Vbat when main power source is not present.

Comment: you need to have LSE for that

Comment: I have LSE, and it is connected to RTC. This is why it is confusing, because everything is as it should be.

Comment: probably you do not update the registers.  Read the reference manual. Do not trust HAL

Comment: Ok I will read the reference manual. However, once MX_RTC_Init() is called, the RTC will keep running and the registers are automatically updated

Comment: As in the song: "if you believe there was a man on the moon".

Comment: RTC works for me - but i do not use HAL for such a simple peripherals.

Comment: RTC works for me too, but on reset it is restarted, whereas it should keep running on Battery and register values should still be updated even when main power is out.

Comment: Intrernal registers - but not registers available for you or reading. It is explained in the RM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check backup state.

Refer to the below code.
it is example for calendar using STM32 series.

```html
/**
  * @brief RTC Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_RTC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 0 */

  RTC_TimeTypeDef sTime = {0};
  RTC_DateTypeDef sDate = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 1 */
  /** Initialize RTC Only
  */
  hrtc.Instance = RTC;
  hrtc.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
  hrtc.Init.AsynchPrediv = 127; ///?// 127;
  hrtc.Init.SynchPrediv = 255;
  hrtc.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutType = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutRemap = RTC_OUTPUT_REMAP_NONE;

  if (HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Check_RTC_BKUP */
  /*##-1- Check if Data stored in BackUp register1: No Need to reconfigure RTC#*/
  /* Read the Back Up Register 1 Data */
  if (HAL_RTCEx_BKUPRead(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR0) != RTC_BKUP_DEFINE_CODE)
  {
    // Clear Backup registor : recover to current RTC information

    // Set to Time/Date from current Time/Date
    
    // Write a data in ad RTC Backup data register
    HAL_RTCEx_BKUPWrite(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR0, RTC_BKUP_DEFINE_CODE);
  } else
  {
    // Only read time and date
    HAL_RTC_GetTime(&hrtc, Time, Format);
    HAL_RTC_GetDate(&hrtc, Date, Format);

  }
  /* USER CODE END Check_RTC_BKUP */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 2 */
  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 2 */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm: I cannot find an example of using VBat to maintain the RTC Clock either;

Just a tip though: The HAL RTC clock intialisation sets the clock and calendar registers to zero, which is a bit quaint. You must remove this from the initialisation code otherwise every time you boot you set the clock to zero:

```
    /**
* @brief RTC Initialization Function
* @param None
* @retval None
*/
static void MX_RTC_Init(void)
{

    /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 0 */
#if TIME_DATE_SET_ON_BOOT == 1
    RTC_TimeTypeDef sTime = {0};
    RTC_DateTypeDef sDate = {0};
#endif

    /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 1 */

    /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 1 */
    /** Initialize RTC Only
    */
    hrtc.Instance = RTC;
    hrtc.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
    hrtc.Init.AsynchPrediv = 127;
    hrtc.Init.SynchPrediv = 255;
    hrtc.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
    hrtc.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
    hrtc.Init.OutPutType = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;
    hrtc.Init.OutPutRemap = RTC_OUTPUT_REMAP_NONE;
    if (HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    /* USER CODE BEGIN Check_RTC_BKUP */

    /* USER CODE END Check_RTC_BKUP */

    /** Initialize RTC and set the Time and Date
    */
#if TIME_DATE_SET_ON_BOOT == 1
    sTime.Hours = 0x0;
    sTime.Minutes = 0x0;
    sTime.Seconds = 0x0;
    sTime.DayLightSaving = RTC_DAYLIGHTSAVING_NONE;
    sTime.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;
    if (HAL_RTC_SetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }
    sDate.WeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
    sDate.Month = RTC_MONTH_JANUARY;
    sDate.Date = 0x1;
    sDate.Year = 0x0;

    if (HAL_RTC_SetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }
#endif
    /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 2 */

/* USER CODE END RTC_Init 2 */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my startup code for an STM32H7B3LIHxQ processor:

```
    int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MPU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/
  MPU_Config();

  /* Enable I-Cache---------------------------------------------------------*/
  SCB_EnableICache();

  /* Enable D-Cache---------------------------------------------------------*/
  SCB_EnableDCache();

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */
    #if BACKEND_PERIPERHALS == 1
    #if (TRAP_DIV_BY_ZERO_HARD_FAULT == 1 && DEBUG_NMI_FAULTS == 1)
  SCB->CCR |= 0x10; // enable div-by-0 trap
    #endif

  /* Enable the Backup System and VBat parameters */
    __HAL_RCC_BKPRAM_CLK_ENABLE();


    HAL_PWREx_DisableBatteryCharging();
    HAL_PWREx_EnableBkUpReg();
    HAL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();

    /* Enable Back up SRAM */
    /* Enable write access to Backup domain */

    PWR->CR1 |= PWR_CR1_DBP;

    while((PWR->CR1 & PWR_CR1_DBP) == RESET)
    {
    }
    #endif
    /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_CRC_Init();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA2D_Init();
  MX_LTDC_Init();
  MX_I2C4_Init();
  MX_OCTOSPI1_Init();
  MX_TouchGFX_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  #if BACKEND_PERIPERHALS == 1
    MX_DMA_Init();
    MX_TIM5_Init();

    #if ADC2_ENABLED == 1
    MX_ADC2_Init();
    MX_TIM3_Init();
    #endif

    MX_CRC_Init();
    MX_I2C1_Init();

    #if OP_AMPS_ENABLED == 1
    MX_OPAMP1_Init();
    MX_OPAMP2_Init();
    #endif

    MX_RNG_Init();
    MX_RTC_Init();
    ...
    
/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Supply configuration update enable
  */

  HAL_PWREx_ConfigSupply(PWR_DIRECT_SMPS_SUPPLY);
  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE0);

  while(!__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_VOSRDY)) {}
  /** Configure LSE Drive Capability
  */

//  __HAL_RCC_BKPRAM_CLK_ENABLE();
//
//  HAL_PWREx_DisableBatteryCharging();
//  HAL_PWREx_EnableBkUpReg();
//  HAL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();
//
//  __HAL_RCC_LSEDRIVE_CONFIG(RCC_LSEDRIVE_LOW);
  /** Macro to configure the PLL clock source
  */


  __HAL_RCC_PLL_PLLSOURCE_CONFIG(RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE);
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI48|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI
                              |RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE
                              |RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSEState = RCC_LSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSIState = RCC_LSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSI48State = RCC_HSI48_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 12;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 280;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLRGE = RCC_PLL1VCIRANGE_1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLVCOSEL = RCC_PLL1VCOWIDE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLFRACN = 0;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D3PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D1PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB3CLKDivider = RCC_APB3_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_APB1_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_APB2_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB4CLKDivider = RCC_APB4_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_RTC|RCC_PERIPHCLK_LTDC
                              |RCC_PERIPHCLK_RNG|RCC_PERIPHCLK_ADC
                              |RCC_PERIPHCLK_I2C1|RCC_PERIPHCLK_I2C4
                              |RCC_PERIPHCLK_OSPI;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL2.PLL2M = 24;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL2.PLL2N = 266;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL2.PLL2P = 2;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL2.PLL2Q = 2;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL2.PLL2R = 2;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL2.PLL2RGE = RCC_PLL2VCIRANGE_0;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL2.PLL2VCOSEL = RCC_PLL2VCOMEDIUM;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL2.PLL2FRACN = 0;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL3.PLL3M = 24;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL3.PLL3N = 201;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL3.PLL3P = 2;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL3.PLL3Q = 2;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL3.PLL3R = 41;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL3.PLL3RGE = RCC_PLL3VCIRANGE_0;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL3.PLL3VCOSEL = RCC_PLL3VCOMEDIUM;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL3.PLL3FRACN = 5462;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.OspiClockSelection = RCC_OSPICLKSOURCE_PLL2;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.RngClockSelection = RCC_RNGCLKSOURCE_HSI48;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.I2c123ClockSelection = RCC_I2C123CLKSOURCE_D2PCLK1;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.I2c4ClockSelection = RCC_I2C4CLKSOURCE_D3PCLK1;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.AdcClockSelection = RCC_ADCCLKSOURCE_PLL2;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.RTCClockSelection = RCC_RTCCLKSOURCE_LSE;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  HAL_RCC_MCOConfig(RCC_MCO1, RCC_MCO1SOURCE_HSI, RCC_MCODIV_1);
}
```

This code works fine. Ican remove the main supply and the clock and backup ram keep ticking away.

Answer (score 0):

Just gone through your code I was also having similar problem.
In your code here is the problem.

```
sAlarm.AlarmTime.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;
```

It should be following

```
sAlarm.AlarmTime.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_SET;
```

In Ioc file go in RTC and change store operation setting to set.
Then uncomment the MX_RTC_Init function.